# use of Angular Spinner with $resource

Tags: angularjs

> I have a problem with angular spinner here, i have a update button
>   in that i'm using spin and loading needs to be stopped after saving the
>   data in to database without using any timeout function i need stop
>   that loading
>   Here i'm using $resouce with promises (subject.update())

```
  function assignLectureToSubject(subject) {
            subject.$update();
        }
```

Html

```
 <td>                
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="vm.assignLectureToSubject(subject)">Update</button>              
 </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your angular version you can pass success and failure callbacks to `$update` method:

```
function assignLectureToSubject(subject) {
  // show spinner

  subject.$update(function(success) {
    // hide spinner here
  }, function(error) {
    // hide spinner here
  });
}
```

or use `finally` callback:

```
subject.$update()
    .then(function(res)  { console.log("called on successful response") })
    .catch(function(req) { console.log("error saving obj"); })
    .finally(function()  { console.log("always called"); // hide spinner here });
```

Comment: still not working giving an error as TypeError: subject.$update.finally is not a function